# How can I use grep to match but without printing the matches?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I'm new to linux shell and am trying to do this, preferably in one line, with the following condition: It can't output anything to the terminal.

```
/var/folder/program.exe -L parameters | grep text_to_filter && echo SomeText >'/tmp/Log.txt'
```

The problem is the .exe spits out XML data to terminal. I can't figure out how to grep, use the exit status, but not have the screen cluttered with the output of each match. If I use `/dev/null 2>&1`, it pipes it quite but then I can't grep the data. Any idea's?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data after trying to grep it?

Comment: consider editing your question to include the desired output to be found in your `/tmp` file. Good luck.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `grep -q` (quiet)

```
/var/folder/program.exe -L parameters |
grep -q "text_to_filter" && echo 'SomeText' > '/tmp/Log.txt'
```

As per `man grep`:

> `-q, --quiet, --silent`
> Quiet;  do  not write anything to standard output.  Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found, even if an error
> was detected.  Also see
> the -s or --no-messages option.

Answer (score 0):

Try using |& rather than just |. (needs bash 4)