# if condition for when a token is not found in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, conditional-statements

I am trying to construct an if-else block wherein one of the conditions is to echo a message if, when running a grep command on a text file, the specified token can not be found.

The grep command is

```
grep -i -n "token" file | cut -d':' -f 1
```

If the token is found, it will return the line number as usual. I want to know how to account for the case when the token does not exist in the text file and the terminal simply outputs nothing when the command is executed.

i.e.

```
if []
  then
    echo "This token does not exist in the file"
  fi
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grep command response silently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841812/grep-command-response-silently)

Comment: just an efficiency comment - improve your regex and remove the `cut`. Don't use 2 processes when one will do.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that's what you need:

```
result=$(grep -i -n "token" file | cut -d':' -f 1)
if [[ -z "$result" ]]; then
    echo "Not found"
else
    echo "$result"
fi
```